# Is it feasible to perform a classification with one feature and Naive Bayes?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, naive-bayes

My question concerns the feasibility of this classification theoretically and realistically.  I mean, if the best performance has been obtained by using only one feature, and adding features degrades the performance:

1- Is there any theoretical reason (related to Naive Bayes) that makes this solution incorrect?  and

2- Is there any reason that makes a solution based on one feature unrealistic?

Additional information that could be useful is that the single feature I'm using is actually a meta-feature that has been computed from other basic features. Based on that, my own point of view concerning the second question is:  using a single feature could be considered realistic because, being a meta-feature, it holds information from many basic features, and so, it could be informative enough for the classification.

Answer (score 1):

Naming a classifier that uses single feature *Naive* Bayes doesn't actually make sense - the point of being *naive* is to simplify problem by assuming that **all** features are independent. For one feature you can just call it a Bayes classifier :)

The whole point of using Naive Bayes classifier is to assume independence, so that you can treat each variable on its own, which simplifies model and makes inference feasible for thousands of features.

> 1- Is there any theoretical reason (related to Naive Bayes) that makes this solution incorrect? and

No.

> 2- Is there any reason that makes a solution based on one feature unrealistic?

Actually Naive Bayes would be mostly used in the situations where you *don't have such knowledge* (and have many features).

Comment: It is not clear for me what do you mean by "in the situations where you don't have such knowledge (and have many features)". Maybe you meant that sometimes from a single feature the class will be evident without the need to a classifier. This may happen if the feature is nominal but if it is a continuous feature this would not be so evident, and training a classifier would be very helpful.

Comment: You wrote that you use 'meta-feature' built from other features. That's feature engineering based on some knowledge (what I meant is that usually you'd just use Naive Bayes when you don't know such features).